# APC Extension unable to load dynamic library /usr/lib/php5/20090626/apcu.so

Tags: php-fpm, memcached, apc

I have installed using this Tutorial https://www.23systems.net/2009/07/installing-alterative-php-cache-apc-with-plesk-on-ubuntu/ and all is running fine. Even APC is caching everything and apc.php shows me all possible results.

But I am getting an error at */var/log/apache2/error.log*

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php5/20090626/apcu.so' - /usr/lib/php5/20090626/apcu.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
```

On all possible php.ini files is the extension added like **extension=apc.so** and if I check the apc.so file inside the folder **/usr/lib/php5/20090626/** than it is called **apc.so** and not **apcu.so**.

I greped all possible known files if I have somewhere mistyped the extension but I could find anything. Installed is the version of ***APC (3.1.13)***.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe I'm wrong, but APCu is newer, renamed version of APC. There is a little mismatch in name, eg. in Ubuntu 14.04 php-apcu is version of php-apc package.

So if one config (extension=apc.so) doesn't work, just try another (extension=apcu.so). Configuration details have "apc.xxxx" in names, not "apcu.xxxx".